# write a csv file on a jenkins slave using groovy

Tags: csv, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to write a csv file from a large json file on a jenkins slave using groovy. Previously the method I used first was only ran on the 'Master' see below:

```
def file = new FilePath(channel, envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'FDCUtilities' + separator + 'GroovyTest' + separator + 'json.json')
def outPutCSV = envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'FDCUtilities' + separator + 'GroovyTest' + separator + 'test.csv'

def results = jsonSlurper.parseText(file.readToString())
def FILE_HEADER = ['ID','TEST NAME','TOTALLINES', 'TOTAL COVERED', 'COVERED %']

new File(outPutCSV).withWriter { fileWriter ->
    csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER)
    results.each{
        csvFilePrinter.printRecord([it.id, it.name, it.totalLines, it.totalCovered, it.coveredPercent])
    }
}
```

Seeing as we can no longer use file and must use 'FilePath' I cannot figure out for the life of me how to the previous csv writer with the new FilePath.  My thought is you just can't as I am having trouble finding documentation where you can either append a file with filepath or write csv's with it. My thought was just to make a string value and assigning csv to the write file, however, I cannot get it to seem to look right or work properly.

My current code:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

// access the files on the current workspace regardless slave or master
def file = new FilePath(channel, envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'FDCUtilities' + separator + 'GroovyTest' + separator + 'json.json')
def outPutCSV = new FilePath(channel, envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'FDCUtilities' + separator + 'GroovyTest' + separator + 'test.csv')

def results = jsonSlurper.parseText(file.readToString())

    test = "ID,TEST NAME,TOTAL LINES,TOTAL COVERED,COVERED %"
    results.each {
        test = test.concat(it.id, it.name, it.totalLines, it.totalCovered, it.coveredPercent, "\n")
    }

    outPutCSV.write(test ,null)
```

I am still learning groovy and jenkins working together so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a "free style project" in jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use Groovy's I/O functions as they would be executed on the Jenkins Master. Always use the [Pipeline DSL steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/), in this case [`writeFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace).

Comment: Problem is here I have literally no idea how to use it even what imports to use with this. I'm very noob.

Comment: In this case, I'd go for [writeCSV](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writecsv-write-content-to-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace) though.

Comment: Sure, nowadays definitely.. this wasn't available back then I think.